# Random Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rss

I am new to nodejs and I am trying to do a rss parser.

I use mongoose for store articles and rss-parser for convert xml to json.

I don't know why, but I have the error : "Random Cannot read property  of null" randomly. Some times the code works, some times not.

```
/* lib require */
var parser = require('rss-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/* Mongodb connection*/

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rss', function(err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
});

/* Schema for mongoose */
var articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    pubDate : String,
    category: String,
    date : { type : Date, default : Date.now }
});

var articleModel = mongoose.model('articles', articleSchema);

/* Array of rss to check */ 
var rssurl = [];

rssurl.push({url: "URL", 
webhook: "LINK";,
category : "CATEGORY"});

rssurl.push({url: "URL", 
webhook: "LINK", 
category: "CATEGORY"});



 /* For each feed, I check if the article exist */

rssurl.forEach(function(item) {
    parser.parseURL(item.url, function(err, parsed) {
        parsed.feed.entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            articleModel.find().count(function(err, count){
                if (count <= 0) {
                    console.log("check");
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Edit : This is the error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'feed' of null
>
> at ~/node_modules/rss-parser/index.js:192:15

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose allows you to begin modeling before your connection succeeds.

Since you say that the error only happens sometimes, my suspicion is one of two things:
Either the connection is failing at a later time, *or* the connection is slow, so it hasn't actually done the work you want to by the time you query the data.

In either case, you could try delaying your work until after the connection succeeds:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rss').then(() => {
    var articleModel = mongoose.model('articles', articleSchema);
    ...
}, (err) => {
    console.log("failure connecting");
    throw err
});
```

If the code succeeds always, then I suspect it's a race condition between connecting to the database and querying the results from it. If you hit the error condition, then you'll know there was an issue connecting in the first place.

Comment: Ok thank you, sorry, I forgot to advise the error, it's : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'feed' of null". Your answer will work for this ?

Comment: In that case, most likely `parseURL` failed. Can you print out the value of `err` in parser.parseURL(item.url, function(err, parsed)) ...

Comment: It doesn't print anything, I have directly the error